# Logging remote file to rsyslog

Tags: remote, rsyslog, download, file-comparison

I have an embedded system that does not support remote logging, but I can download its log file over HTTP, e.g. with:

```
wget http://192.168.1.1/status/syslog.log
```

I'd like to use a third machine to get that log regularly and log new content with `rsyslog`. Before I start scripting, is there a standard solution I could use? I could not find one.